# Show 1 row on desktop and 2 rows on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This basic bootstrap CSS shows me 4 columns on 1 row:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        Text
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        Text
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        Text
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        Text
    </div>
</div>
```

For the mobile view I would like to display 2 columns on 2 rows. The only way that I know how to do this is to create the same content twice ... something like this:

```
<div class="desktop">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            Text
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            Text
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            Text
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            Text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mobile">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            Text
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            Text
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            Text
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            Text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So you can set `display:none` for the classes desktop and mobile using `@media` ...

That would work but it is not the cleanest solution. Would there be another way to do this?

Comment: You can combine multiple classes at once separating by space. See @niyasc answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to write separate code for smaller devices and larger devices. Following code snippet will serve your purpose.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
    4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: They all are displayed. But the difference is the wide of the column depending on the devices. And the OP is trying to show or hide the rows in that devices.

Comment: Yes. They are displayed in a single row in larger devices and in two rows for smaller devices. I think that what OP is asking for.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal from the OP you can see that the content is the same both ih the `desktop` and `mobile` container, so @niyasc solution is also good.

Comment: @niyasc You were absolutely right. I found your answer is correct after re-reading the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That really works. I just thought the sum of the columns should always be 12 as it is for col-md. The sum of col-xs is in your case 24. So yes, it works but I don't know why it works.

Comment: What if you have more divs? I'm trying to work with 16. If I use, say, "xs-12, md-4, lg-3", then every X 'rows' it skips till the last spot, so on lg, it skips a space for "lg-9", on md it skips a space for "md-8", and so on. What can I do?